# Why isn't the length of a second correct?

Tags: javascript, time

I have a javascript program like such:

```
function addtime() {
  curtime = document.getElementById("time").value * 1000;
  curtime += 1;
  document.getElementById("time").value = curtime / 1000;
}
setInterval(function () {
  addtime();
}, 1);
```

You may see in my code that I am multiplying by 1000 and then dividing by 1000, and this is because I want to increment by a millisecond every time, but show the amount of seconds in the "time" output div. But when I opened the page which had this code in it, a second is not actually "a second", if you understand what I mean. It is currently three times longer than the normal second, and I don't know why.

So what is the problem in my code, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Lucas

Comment: i think it's because you call addTime(); every millisec. that means a thousand calls per sec, which your navigator can't surely handle, therefore you'll see the number grow slower than it should.

Comment: so what should I do to fix the problem, and what do you mean by `post "time" value`?

Comment: Why do you multiply and divide by 1000? What exactly do you want to be shown in the `#time` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that JavaScript is not guaranteed to call setInterval at exactly the time you specify, but at the first opportunity it has after that time has passed. Also, 1ms is waaaay under the resolution of a lot of (all?) browsers.

To do this properly, get the start time, then find out the elapsed milliseconds by subtracting the current time.

```
var start = new Date();
var update = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var elapsed = now - start;
    // now you can do something with `elapsed`,
    // like stuff it into the UI
};
setInterval(update, 100);
```

Comment: +1 current-start is indeed the way to go. That way, even if the browser "hangs" for a couple of seconds, it will auto-correct afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=72wh5PnEf1k#t=2355s) where J. Resig explains how JavaScript has innacurate timers, in context to his presentation about using timers in testing.

*"OSX timers are precise, to the milisecond. But in Windows, the timer is only updated every 15ms."*

here's [another article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/) by N. Zakas, that points out that timer resolution is different in some cases and it depends on the browser also. 1ms resolution is fast, but it will take a big bite in CPU processing, that's why browsers pull it back. As far as i know, browsers throttle down timers (as well as rendering), when the tab is not in focus.

i see this in chrome a lot, especially in slow PCs where opening 4 tabs at once of the same page, only the one in focus *renders* first (clockwise fast icon), while the others continue to load (counter-clockwise loading icon).

Comment: well, that may be due to the browser, as well as other factors. i haven't found docs that explain much of it though, just the ones i provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a second of interval set an interval of a second instead of increasing the time by milliseconds increase it by seconds. Then you can simplify your value updating code too.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/NGTXU/

```
setInterval(function () {
   document.getElementById("time").value++;
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

since `setInterval` takes argument as milisecond, i think you should replace `1` with `1000`

```
function addtime() {
  curtime = document.getElementById("time").value * 1000;
  curtime += 1;
  document.getElementById("time").value = curtime / 1000;
}
setInterval(function () {
  addtime();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Keeping time by `setInterval` is known to be imprecise, and should be discouraged.

Comment: @Amadan: please give me details of this. i can't understand.

Comment: See links in Joseph's answer.

Comment: @Amadan: Thanks. I am exploring those links.

Comment: But I only changed it to 1 to be able to update my #time field every millisecond.